# Ezjail and /etc/jail.conf in FreeBSD 10.2

Tags: freebsd, jail

I have a question regarding the following warning when using
Ezjail-3.4.1 on FreeBSD 10.2
/etc/rc.d/jail: WARNING: Per-jail configuration via jail_* var "enter code here" iables  is obsolete.  Please consider to migrate to /etc/jail.conf "enter code here"It is my understanding that this has changed in FreeBSD 9.0 but since 10.2 the new way is the default method and that warning is being generated.I haven't been able to find any information about this on google, a lot of users mentioning the errors but ignoring them because their jails still work.AFAIK in 10.0 the rc.d/jail script converts the old-style jail_
variables into a temporary jail.conf to handle the jail. So the warning
is generated by rc.d/jail

Regards 
Mr-Hill

Comment: That seems to be reasonably correct. What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

As you found out, jails on FreeBSD 10.x use a new configuration method. [From `/usr/src/UPDATING`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/stable/10/UPDATING#L281-L298):

```
20131010:
    The rc.d/jail script has been updated to support jail(8)
    configuration file.  The "jail_<jname>_*" rc.conf(5) variables
    for per-jail configuration are automatically converted to
    /var/run/jail.<jname>.conf before the jail(8) utility is invoked.
    This is transparently backward compatible.  See below about some
    incompatibilities and rc.conf(5) manual page for more details.

    These variables are now deprecated in favor of jail(8) configuration
    file.  One can use "rc.d/jail config <jname>" command to generate
    a jail(8) configuration file in /var/run/jail.<jname>.conf without
    running the jail(8) utility.   The default pathname of the
    configuration file is /etc/jail.conf and can be specified by
    using $jail_conf or $jail_<jname>_conf variables.

    Please note that jail_devfs_ruleset accepts an integer at
    this moment.  Please consider to rewrite the ruleset name
    with an integer.
```

ezjail was [never updated to use this new method](http://erdgeist.org/arts/software/ezjail/#version-history), but that's ok: FreeBSD still accepts the previous method. You can ignore this warning.